# my ceiling fan fell and i wanna know how to wire the leftover wires sticking out of the ceiling?

Tags: ceiling-fan

[image]at the moment half the room has no power and the fan did have a switch just in case that helps. [image]
as you can see in the pic ive already attempted to wire it and i manged to get power back to part of the room but the side of the room with the switch still has no power

Comment: What's all the tape doing there?  Did the whole junction box fall down out of the ceiling?

Comment: Yes, did the fan disengage from the box and fall down, or did the box fall out of the ceiling with the fan? Can we have photos that look squarely upwards into the box (or ex-box) location, as well as the back of the switch box?

Comment: the fan disengaged and fell down and ill get the pics ,thank you

Comment: Also, what make and model is this fan? It seems like a flat-out installation error, given that the mounting bracket is still firmly anchored to the ceiling box...